# Hibernate HQL new Constructor VarArgs

Tags: hibernate, variadic-functions

I am using hibernate Version 3.2.5 i have a HQL like this:

```
select new org.com.Utilities.Inventario.ReporteInventario(P.Id,P.Name,DP.Rotacion,LongResult,IntegerResult,IntegerResult,IntegerResult,IntegerResult,IntegerResult,IntegerResult,)
```

and i have a constructor in this way:

```
public ReporteInventario(
        String CodPro,
        String NomProd,
        String RotProd,
        Long TotalStock,
        Integer Val1,
        Integer Val2,
        Integer Val3,
        Integer Val4,
        Integer Val5,
        Integer Val6)
```

works OK. But i have tried the following:

```
public ReporteInventario(
    String CodPro,
    String NomProd,
    String RotProd,
    Long TotalStock,
    Integer.. Array)
```

But i'm receiving not Compliant Constructor found. i am not big fan of verbosity. my question is can i use Varargs in my Constructor whose Hibernate can populate. thanks a lot.

Comment: It will help a bit if you try to format your code so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Java?  (It seems not from your coding convention).

If so, though I haven't tried, I believe what you need is to pass in an Integer array to the vararg argument.  Because in Java, vararg is in fact an array, and that's only a syntax sugar that compiler helps to change your "arguments" to an array.

However I don't think there is any way to create an array in HQL

Therefore, stick to your first method signature.

Comment: Thanks.. but i need to use a Varargs class constructor in a HQL query using new myClass(). because i am creating a dynamic HQL and sometimes returns 2 or 3 integers..something like select A,B,C or A,B,C,D all i need is create a Constructor Using Varargs to create only one contructor a works for no matter know many integers i am retrieving.. i would want this works. MyClass(String,String,Long,VarArgs for Integer)

Comment: haven't tried, but seems in hql, you can new a list (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html , section 16.6).  Change the method signature of your constructor to receive List instead of vararg, and construct the list and pass in as one of the ctor argument.  Dunno if it works but worth a try I think

Comment: I have tried. Select new org.com.Utilities.Inventario.ReporteInventario(P.Id,P.Name,DP.Rotacion,(Select sum(DP.Stock) from DP where P.Id=DP.Producto.Id),new list((Select DP.Stock as Stock0 from DP where P.Id=DP.Producto.Id And DP.Sucursal.Id=1200),(Select DP.Stock as Stock1 from DP where P.Id=DP.Producto.Id And DP.Sucursal.Id=1300))) and change the constructor to public ReporteInventario(String CodPro,String NomProd,String RotProd,Long TotalStock,java.util.List Stocks){System.out.println("Worked");}  but iam getting unexpected token: new near line 1, column 140 on the new list